# Excel: Two variables to be checked against 5x4 matrix

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I need to calculate a specific constant, KM (column G in uploaded spreadsheet) that is in a conditional 5x4 matrix based on two variables (windspeed and Delta T) in excel. I'm looking for a code that checks windspeed and delta T for each row and then go through the matrix and check what conditions are met and post the constant that corresponds to that condition.

I am myself not sure what way to go on this as this go past the limit of if statements in excel. Is there any way this can be done in vba?

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1fzxaxp3mummqz/weatherdata.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really need VBA to get this constant, here is a solution with standard worksheet formula:

`=INDEX($L$5:$O$9,MATCH(E3,$K$5:$K$9,1),MATCH(F3,$L$4:$O$4,1))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm and proves that I am not trained in programming not being able to grasp that there might be an easier solution ;)